# Where is the iWork shape library stored?

Tags: pages, keynote, iwork, macos

I created a *Custom Shape Library* via iWork and would like to share it within my company. Where is this library located so I can copy/paste it to all other users?

I already found where custom templates for Pages and the color palettes are stored. Yet I struggle to find the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shapes are stored in the property list at

```
~/Library/Group Containers/74J34U3R6X.com.apple.iWork/Library/Preferences/74J34U3R6X.com.apple.iWork.plist
```

in the array `TSDUserDefinedShapeLibraryPathSourcesKey`.

[image]

Comment: I've added a custom shape in pages, but it does not show up here.