# Where is the keynote shape library stored?

Tags: keynote

I have a set of 'custom shapes' pre built in Keynote, which I'd like to share within my company. Where is the library located, so I can copy/paste for all other users?

Comment: Wouldn’t you just post your keynote document for them to use on shared storage? Maybe a screen shot of the interface you wish to modify would help us help you further.

Answer (score 2):

Although I know this may overwrite user keynote preferences, the folder 'com.apple.iWork.Keynote' stored in the containers folder seems to hold the stored user shapes.

Library > Containers > com.apple.iWork.Keynote

Comment: i can't find my shapes here. Could you be more specific?
I'd like to create shapes from svgs or a conversion tool.

edit: i found https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/304894/109779